# Writing to CSV Issues

Tags: php, fwrite

The output file doesn't seem to be placing data properly into the CSV

```
include_once ('database_connection.php');//Including our DB Connection file
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){//IF the url contains the parameter "keyword"
 $keyword =     trim($_GET['keyword']) ;//Remove any extra  space
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);//Some validation

$query = "select topictitle,topicdescription from topics where topictitle like '%$keyword%' or topicdescription like '%$keyword%'";
//The SQL Query that will search for the word typed by the user .

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);//Run the Query
if($result){//If query successfull
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){//and if atleast one record is found
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ //Display the record
 echo '<p> <b>'.$row['topictitle'].'</b> '.$row['topicdescription'].'</p>
 <input type="text" value="'.$_GET['keyword'].'" /><input type="text" value="'.$row['topicdescription'].'" />
 '   ;

                $numbre = fopen($_GET['keyword'].'.csv',"w");
                echo fwrite($numbre, "topictitle,topicdescription\r\n");
                echo fwrite($numbre, $_GET['topictitle'].",&".$_GET['topicdescription']);
                fclose($numbre);

 }
 }else {
 echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';//No Match found in the Database
 }

}
}else {
 echo 'Parameter Missing in the URL';//If URL is invalid
}
```

The output file places everything except for the topicdescription.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line :

```
echo fwrite($numbre, "topictitle,topicdescription\r\n");
```

Use this

```
echo fwrite($numbre, $row['topictitle'] . "," . $row['topicdescription'] . "\r\n");
```

Also change `$_GET['topictitle']` and `$_GET['topicdescription']` to `$row['topictitle']` and `$row['topicdescription']`

Comment: Thanks works. I've been working on this for hours can't believe I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `echo fwrite($numbre, $_GET['topictitle'].",&".$_GET['topicdescription']);` do you mean to write `$row["topictitle"]` and `$row["topicdescription"]` from the DB query to the CSV rather than URL parameters?

Comment: What I want to do is if displayed results show foo and bar for the topictitle and topicdescription then write those to the csv file.

Comment: Ok. Did you see woofmeow's post?  He said what I was sort of getting at. Will that work?